# RESTFUL url design in handleOpenUrl

Tags: iphone, objective-c, regex, ios, openurl

One of my main tabs is a uiwebview, which links to resources across the application.

As such, I am building a restful router in my handleOpenUrl. But my regex/obj-c string handling is pretty poor, so i would love to get some help for parsing the following routes

```
/topics/:id/
/topics/:id/answers
/users/:id/answers/:answer_id
/questions?text=xxxyyy
```

Any advice would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest that you just pass a JSON object instead?  If you want a good reference for how to structure your json objects, see this suggestion for JSON Remote Procedure Call:

http://json-rpc.org/